# ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) when using texblock with cm

Tags: positioning, textpos

When I use `textblock` without cm is ok.

Example:

```
\begin{textblock}{14}(0.5,0.5)
```

But when I add cm:

```
\begin{textblock}{14cm}(0.5cm,0.5cm)
```

The error in the log is:

> `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Please guide me, need cm or without cm when using `textblock`.

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal self contained example, that gives others a better idea of what you are doing and code to test.

Comment: Additionally where does the `textblock` env come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a google search of `latex textblock` I assume you are using the `textpos` package. A quick glance to its documentation shows:

> The `{textblock}` parameters ⟨*hsize*⟩, ⟨*hpos*⟩ and ⟨*vpos*⟩ are multiples or fractions of the horizontal and vertical modules, as appropriate. If you want or need to give explicit sizes here, see the `{textblock*}` environment below.